# How do I efficiently extract the values in a _recordset into an stl container

Tags: c++, stl, ado

What is the most efficient way of "*converting*" an ADO _Recordset into an stl vector or map?  That is, I want to take all of the (string) values in the Recordset and push them onto a vector if there is only one Field, or push them onto a map if there are two Fields.  I know ahead of time whether the Recordset contains one or two Fields and I also know that each value is unique.

Currently I do something like below for a recordset with only one field.

```
While(false == EOF)
{
   myRecorset->get_Fields(&myFields);
   myFields->get_Item(1, &myField);
   myField->get_Value(&fieldValue);
   myVector.push_back(fieldValue.bstrVal);
)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What is "ADO _RecordSet"? If it is a class, please include its declaration.

Comment: "ADO"  is "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects" and _Recordset is an interface of the [Recordset Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordset-object-ado?view=sql-server-2017)